# Laplace transform with initial value problem $y''+4y=12\sin(2t)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Using Laplace transforms solve the initial value problem.
$$y''+4y
=
12\text{sin}(2t);
\qquad\qquad
y(\pi)=-3, \quad y'(\pi)=-3$$

I have begun with writing:

- $\mathcal{L} (y'') = s^2y(s) -s y(\pi) -y'(\pi)$ = $s^2y(s)+3s+3$
- $\mathcal{L} (4y) = 4y(s)$
- $\mathcal{L} (12sin(2t)) = \frac{24}{s^2+4}$

So I got:

$$y(s) = \frac{24}{(s^2+4)^2}-\frac{3s}{s^2+4}-\frac{3}{s^2+4}$$

Using inverse laplace transforms:

- $\mathcal{L}^{-1} (\frac{3s}{s^2+4}) = 3\,\text{cos}\,(2t)$
- $\mathcal{L}^{-1} (\frac{3}{s^2+4}) = \frac{3}{2}\,\text{sin}\,(2t)$

I think what I got until here is correct (at least I hope so). The problem is:

- $\mathcal{L}^{-1} (\frac{24}{(s^2+4)^2}) = \quad?$

I think I can do this by using convolution theorem but I am not sure. Taking $24$ aside, I have

$\frac{1}{s^2+4}$ and $\frac{1}{s^2+4}$. They are both $\frac{1}{2}\text{sin}(2t)$. I think I can write them by convolution problem as:

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{t}\text{sin}(2t-2\tau)\,\text{sin}(2\tau)\,\text{d}\tau$$

But I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to see my another answer below using convolution theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another answer. Your approach using convolution theorem is correct.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}\sin(2t-2\tau)\,\sin2\tau\ d\tau&=\int_{0}^{t}(\sin2t\cos2\tau-\cos2t\sin2\tau)\sin2\tau\ d\tau\\
&=\sin2t\int_{0}^{t}\cos2\tau\sin2\tau\ d\tau-\cos2t\int_{0}^{t}\sin^22\tau\ d\tau\\
&=\sin2t\int_{0}^{t}\frac12\sin4\tau\ d\tau-\cos2t\int_{0}^{t}\frac12(1-\cos4\tau)\ d\tau\\
&=-\frac18\sin2t\left.\cos4\tau\right|_0^t-\frac12\cos2t\left[\tau-\frac14\sin4\tau\right]_0^t\\
&=-\frac18\sin2t\cos4t+\frac18\sin2t-\frac t2\cos2t+\frac18\cos2t\sin4t\\
&=\frac18\sin(4t-2t)+\frac18\sin2t-\frac t2\cos2t\\
&=\frac14\sin2t-\frac t2\cos2t\\
&=\frac14(\sin2t-2t\cos2t).
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{24}{(s^2+4)^2}\right]=24\cdot\frac14\int_{0}^{t}\sin(2t-2\tau)\,\sin2\tau\ d\tau=\frac32(\sin2t-2t\cos2t).
$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT :**
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{2a^3}{(s^2+a^2)^2}\right]=\sin at-at\cos at.
$$

Comment: Take $a=2$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{24}{(s^2+4)^2}\right]&=\frac32\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{2\cdot 2^3}{(s^2+2^2)^2}\right]
=\frac32(\sin 2t-2t\cos 2t).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Do I need to memorize this for my exam? Because it was a previous exam question and its solution begins with $u = t - \pi$ and goes from there but I could not understand the solution. Is my solution way correct?

Comment: @goktugerce I've checked your convolution approach, it's also **correct**. It will yield the same result as my answer. My lecturer gave me using Laplace table when I took the exam. **:P**